# Prove that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ implies there exists some $c$ such that $f(x)=cx$ for all rational numbers $x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions, solution-verification

> suppose $f$ satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$. **question a)** prove that $f(x_1+...x_n)=f(x)+...+f(x_n)$ **question b)** prove that there is some numbers $c$ such that $f(x)=cx$ for all rational numbers $x$(at this point we're not trying to say anything about $f(x)$ for irrational $x$).Hint :First figure out what $c$ must be .now prove that $f(x)=cx$ .first when $x$ is a natural numbers,then when $x$ is an integer ,then when $x$ is the reciprocal of an integer and ,finally for all rational $x$

this question from spivak calculus book chap3,problem 16

the question $a$ is trivial i proved it by  mathematical induction.

for the question b,i know how to solve it using the steps in the hint, but also  tried to solve it without respect those steps.

my attempt:

if there is some $c$ such that $f(x)=cx$ , then $f(x+y)=cx+cy$ that's means c can be writen as $c=\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}$

so now we if we can show that   for any rational $x$ there is some $y$ such that $f(x)=\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}.x$ then we will finish.

$f(x)=\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}.x$$\Leftrightarrow$$ xf(x)+yf(x)=xf(x+y)$$\Leftrightarrow$$xf(x)+yf(x)=xf(x)+xf(y)$$\Leftrightarrow$$yf(x)=xf(y)$.which is true for any numbes $x=y$, so for all  rational  $x$ there is some numbers  $y$ such this  $f(x)=\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}.x$ wich means there is some numbers $c$ such that $f(x)=cx$.for all  rational $x$.

so i  think i proved it for any  rational $x$.but also I doubt if my proof  is logical

so

- does my proof is true?.

note:(i want to see if my proof is true,if you have an other proof ,post it as an answer or in comment but don't close my question)

Comment: $f(x)$ is not necessarily $cx$ for irrational $x$. You might want to find $f(n)= f(\underbrace{1+1+\cdots + 1}_{n})$ using part (a). Next, consider $f( \underbrace{\frac{p}{q} + \cdots + \frac{p}{q}}_{q})$. You must use $x$ is rational in some way. It is not true that $f$ is linear on all of $\mathbb{R}$, which is what your claim suggests.

Comment: This is [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), a lot can be found about that.

Answer (score 1):

> if there is some $c$ such that $f(x)=cx$ , then $f(x+y)=cx+cy$ that's means c can be writen as $c=\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}$

Yes, that is correct. However, the rest of your reasoning seems to be based on the opposite implication. Which you didn't prove.

The classical solution is as follows:

1. By induction (what you've already proved) $f(n\cdot x)=n\cdot f(x)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
2. If $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=f(1/n)$ then by 1. we have $n\cdot a=f(n\cdot 1/n)=f(1)$, i.e. $a=f(1)/n$, or equivalently $f(1/n)=f(1)/n$.

combining both we get

$$f(p/q)=f(1)\cdot p/q$$
which completes the proof.